# Angular 4 - Can not proccess response of server

Tags: javascript, angular, get

I'm developing an Angular 4 web application and I'm having some problems when I try ask a remote server for data:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://viacep.com.br/ws/39400001/json/. Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Before you say this is a CORS problem in the server (I'm not the server owner), I should say that the requests using programs like Insomnia works like a charm and I have a code in AngularJS 1.x that works with this same server and with almost same code. If you look at chrome console, you will see the server responding to the request with the expected data:

[image: Response as expected]
[image: Request to the server]

I really believe I forgot something in Angular configuration or in my request:

```
@Injectable()
export class ViaCepService {

    constructor(private http:Http) {
    }

    find(cep:string):Observable<ViaCepResponse> {
        return this.http.get("https://viacep.com.br/ws/" + cep + "/json/").map((res:Response) => {
            return res.json();
        });
    }
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: So you're getting a CORS error but you claim it's working?

Comment: :) I will reformulate this part...

Comment: I updated the question. I put this way because I believe the problem is not with the server, is with the client. I have another code in AngularJS 1.x that works correctly making the same request.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's definitely a CORS issue. I've had similar issues, whilst applications outside of the browser don't have them, my Angular app running in the browser fails.

For me, I proved the issue was CORS related by installing Telerik Fiddler on my machine and intercepting the request/response messages and injecting or modifying the response headers. My browser was definitely receiving the data (like in your scenario), but the CORS issues (lack of correct header in response) stopped the data from hitting my Angular app.

For more info on CORS issues (including yours), here is a good resource

https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-cors-protocol